# Getting DOM events back after stored in Session Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, clone

```
function setItemStates() {
    savedItemState = $('#my-items').clone(true, true);
    sessionStorage.setItem('savedItemState', savedItemState.html());
}
function getItemStates() {
    var domElem = sessionStorage.getItem('savedItemState');
    domElem = $(domElem);
    $('body').html(domElem) // No events or state
}
```

---

I'm looking for a way to get my DOM events back after I have cloned and saved to sessionStorage.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not possible as you're saving the HTML as a string, and it has no concept of events or data.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a way to store the events and apply them to the html after? Still searching

Comment: And you're getting the innerHTML so you're not really recreating `#my-items`, that element is lost ?

Comment: Nope, tried some tests, objects are converted to strings, so there's no way to keep events and data in storage, the only option would be delegated event handlers, but that's not very helpful for cross session storage of elements. If you don't really need to store the elements across pageloads, you should store the elements in variables and use `detach` instead.

Comment: Why can you not use jquery .on()?

Comment: I need it to be in the session since I'm dealing with users. I'll take a look at delegated event handlers @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to use delegated event handlers instead of binding the events directly on your element.

For example:

```
$(document).on("click", "#my-items", function(e) {
...
});
```

instead of:

```
$("#my-items").on("click", function(e) {
...
});
```